# Symfony 4 installation with composer error mkdir(): No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4, symfony-flex

when i do

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton project
```

I have this error on Windows : [ErrorException]  mkdir(): No such file or directory.

php version : 7.1.9

composer version : 1.6.2

Do you have any idea on this error ?

Comment: Traditionally you would install something like git bash to give you a basic set of unix commands such as mkdir.

Comment: Agreed, i already use git bash

Comment: Works fine with same config (php and git bash) but composer 1.5.2. Strange...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I rollback to the 1.5.2 version and it's work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @damienbodilis Post your comment as an answer to help the future readers :D

Answer (score 0):

I rollback to the 1.5.2 version and it's work. Thanks for your help.